# Frame-by-frame animation or video animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I need to use animations in the app. Is it better to use frame-to-frame `ImageView` animations or to use video animations? Video animations are SWF (which I can probably convert to mp4).

The animations last up to 4s what would be around 80 images in one frame-to-frame animation. This is the layout of the app.

[image]

A different animation will appear in the red area based on which button on the right side is pressed.

Now, which approach is best to use?

- I know that frame-to-frame approach may create an app with a lot of MBs.
- I also do not know if video approach could make smooth animations? Can I play SWF files inside the such layout or I would have to convert each into mp4 in order to use this app on pre-Android-2.2 mobile phones.

Please advise!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785336/starting-frame-by-frame-animation I hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: @MansiVora Hm, this does not answer my question. I know how to implement frame-by-frame (it's easy) but I do not now should I use it or video file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ImageView, I assume you will be doing the animation by repeatedly calling the `invalidate` method. This will not give you a high frame rate. To do real-time animation, you need a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) or subclass thereof, perhaps a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html).

Comment: In XML I set the resource with each image and its duration. Then in code I just setDrawable for ImageView. I do not think I'd need SurfaceView for this.