# animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I have created animation.xml file in which i have added my stuff of frame animation but it is not working  i have called 5this in my activity class as follow....

```
animation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
        animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);      // the frame-by-frame animation defined as a xml file within the drawable folder
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = 
                (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
```

can any one tell me what is problem in that

**animation.xmal file**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_8" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_9" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_14" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_15" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_16" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_17" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_18" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_19" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_20" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_21" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_22" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_23" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_24" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_25" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_26" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_27" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_28" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_29" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_30" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_31" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_32" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_33" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_34" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_35" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_36" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_37" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_38" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_39" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_40" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_41" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_42" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_43" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_44" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_45" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_46" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_47" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_48" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anatomy_49" android:duration="50" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785336/starting-frame-by-frame-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

put your `animation.xml` file in `anim` folder

**Simple Animation**

```
Animation rAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(your_context, R.anim.animation);
animation.startAnimation(rAnim);
```

where `animation` is your `imageview`

**update**

**Drawable Animation**

```
    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
      rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
      rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
       final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    { wait(1000);      
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run()
    {
     rocketAnimation.start();
    }});
     }
});
thread.start();

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        rocketAnimation.start();
        return true;
      }
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: what is act ? can you explain?

Comment: it is throwing me runtime exception as Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: animation-list

Comment: but i want that when my activity start then my animation is also get started ....

Comment: then write this code **rocketAnimation.start();** in oncreate method

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run()
it is showing me error on this line on activity  as undefine variable

Comment: oh my dear. activity is your current activity.. use your classname.this instead of activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11921/discussion-between-ashishsingh-and-capdroid)

Comment: you have seen my qoustion stackoverflow.com/questions/10810291/convert-image-into-bitmap

Answer (score 3):

As seen at the bottom of [drawable animation example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) page:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the
>   AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of
>   your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached
>   to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without
>   requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the
>   [onWindowFocusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) method in your Activity, which will get called
>   when Android brings your window into focus.

Hope it helps.. ;) Cheers

Comment: This is one of the best points given here. Not starting the animation during `OnCreate()`!

Answer (score 1):

make folder **anim** in **res** and put your **animation.xml** in **anim** folder and than use this way

```
 Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation);
 imageview.setAnimation(anim); 
 or
 imageview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: it is throwing me the java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: animation-list