# Animation in loading listview

Tags: android, android-animation

I made a listview ,when i scroll the listview the a loading circle is working at the footer before get the next list items.
The loading circle is set and get from listview

```
public void setLoadingView(View listFooter) {
    this.listFooter = listFooter;
}

public View getLoadingView() {
    return listFooter;
}
```

This is xml for circle

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"

    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/pencil"
        android:textColor="#B36000" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

And then set this layout in listview.
Now what i have to done is i need to replace a pen in loading circle where the pen is animated.Its animated like the pen is writing.(its like when someone write in skype, show a pen on the screen writing).I have 4 pics for this pen animation.Actually i don't understand what to do :(...
I am new in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame). Seems, all You need is to create animation resource and provide it as background for ImageView. Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785336/starting-frame-by-frame-animation) for some code snippets and details on how to start an animation.