# Moving images automatically from right to left inside a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am moving images in my layout from right to left with a delay of 1000ms. The application used absolute layout and redraw the images dynamically. Is there any other way to do it?? Like  the images in scroll View or Some animation?

Answer (score 0):

you can do frame-by-frame animation in android; frame-by-frame animation is defined in an xml file and then used within the activity to start the animation.

To do this AnimationDrawable class is used.

see this duplicate question [Starting Frame-By-Frame Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785336/starting-frame-by-frame-animation) which may help.

And the almost exact example can be found from [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/frame-animation/).

Also you can check the other good example at [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html) which is beginner guide for this.